NetSuite Workbook Stacked Column Chart Combining X-Axis
I have a stacked column chart in a NetSuite Workbook. There are three x-axis values – 'Design', 'EIC', and 'PTO' that contain a 1/0 (complete/incomplete) value to indicate if each stage has been completed for projects in a date range. The 'Color Stack' and 'Measure' are both 'Assigned To' (a user). Each user will have a few items in each of the three stacks. The idea is to have 3 columns containing the number of completed items for each user in each stack.
What I'm getting is a single stack that combines the three x-axis fields. How do I get it to show them as separate columns?
Current Chart Results
